# Get access to current Ember route inside component

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have my custom Ember component which is inside a controller.

Now I am trying to get the current route name dynamically

So I get access to the controller using

```
this.get('parentView')
```

But I am unable to get the current route name after this. How do I get the current route name ?
I tried doing

```
this.get('parentView').routeName
```

Answer (score 2):

In ember `2.15` will be a router service for this. Currently there [is a polypill for older ember versions](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-router-service-polyfill).

Edit: Ember 2.15 has been released on September 1, 2017. You find some information about RouterService in [release notes](https://emberjs.com/blog/2017/09/01/ember-2-15-released.html#toc_public-router-service-phase-1) and [api documentation](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/RouterService). Please note that api docs currently does not mention properties exposed due to missing documentation in code. Additionally to ember-router-service-polyfill you could also access private [RoutingService](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/RoutingService) via `-routing` in earlier releases.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't implement a logic according to the current route in a component. Your components should not be aware of the route they are been placed. But of course there may some exceptional cases, such as breadcrump components, menu components...

Anyway, the answers of your question are:

1. By using `application controller`:

`application controller` has a `currentRouteName` property.

You can use `application controller` such as:

```
Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('controller:application').get('currentRouteName')
```

2. By using `router`:

Either inject the [*private* `-router` service](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/RoutingService) to your component or lookup for the router instance such as:

```
 Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('router:main').get('currentRouteName');
```

Comment: You can't inject controller other than controller instance.

Answer (score 0):

In ember 3.20 I can access the current route name in this way

```
this.YOURAPP._applicationInstances.values().next().value.router.currentRouteName
```